# How to run a bash script that takes multiple user intactive inputs , as part of dockerfile

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile, zap

I have the below dockerfile that needs to run a owasp bash file for its intallation.
This .sh file needs multiple inputs(like 1, Y, enter) from the user for the completion of installation.

How do I provide these inputs from dockerfile or is there a way to skip these inputs and continue the installation.

This dockerfile is a part of the docker-compose.

Below is thew dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get clean
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN apt-get install vim -y

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Indian

# Install OpenJDK-8
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get clean;

# Fix certificate issues
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install ca-certificates-java && \
    apt-get clean && \
    update-ca-certificates -f

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME

RUN apt-get install wget -y && \
    apt-get install unzip -y && \
    apt-get install zip -y

RUN mkdir /home/owasp

RUN wget -c https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/releases/download/v2.11.0/ZAP_2_11_0_unix.sh -P /home/owasp

RUN chmod u+x /home/owasp/ZAP_2_11_0_unix.sh
RUN ./home/owasp/ZAP_2_11_0_unix.sh
```

Comment: Can you modify the script to not require interactive input, or somehow pass its settings via a non-interactive configuration file?  Or, use one of the [prebuilt ZAP images](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/about/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide input for command use some input generator and pipe it with your command.

Typical example is using command `yes` which provides endless stream of "y" on output:

```
RUN yes|./own-shell-scrpit.sh
```

You can run `printf 'y\n1abc\nxxx'` and pipe it. "\n" in `printf` states for newline (or enter).

Comment: the stream of inputs differ, starting with Enter, then 1,1,1,..thenY,Y...likewise

Comment: Which part of answer you do not understand?

Comment: Thanks a ton . It worked. I had to combine input and Enter (1\n)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Linux Package : https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/releases/download/v2.11.0/ZAP_2.11.0_Linux.tar.gz
That has the same contents but is just a gziped tar file :)
Full list of ZAP downloads available is on https://www.zaproxy.org/download/

Or you can always extend our docker images https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Simon. I was aware of the docker image but needed to install it on an ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a `ENTRYPOINT` so it by default will invoke your bash script, but it gives the flexibily to the end user to pass different arguments. See the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint). Keep in mind the `CMD` provided in a Dockerfile is a [default command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact). You override it by passing any other value.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Indian

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get clean
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN apt-get install vim -y

# Install OpenJDK-8
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get clean;

# Fix certificate issues
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install ca-certificates-java && \
    apt-get clean && \
    update-ca-certificates -f

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME

RUN apt-get install wget -y && \
    apt-get install unzip -y && \
    apt-get install zip -y

RUN mkdir /home/owasp

RUN wget -c https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/releases/download/v2.11.0/ZAP_2_11_0_unix.sh -P /home/owasp

RUN chmod u+x /home/owasp/ZAP_2_11_0_unix.sh

ENTRYPOINT ./home/owasp/ZAP_2_11_0_unix.sh

CMD ['--some', '--default', '--args']
```

You can even choose to pass default flags on build. So your script will then always run with default flags you provided on `docker build --build-args DEFAULT_PARAMS=--foo`, unless you override it:

```
ARGS DEFAULT_PARAMS

FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEFAULT_PARAMS=${DEFAULT_PARAMS}
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Indian

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get clean
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN apt-get install vim -y

# Install OpenJDK-8
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get clean;

# Fix certificate issues
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install ca-certificates-java && \
    apt-get clean && \
    update-ca-certificates -f

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME

RUN apt-get install wget -y && \
    apt-get install unzip -y && \
    apt-get install zip -y

RUN mkdir /home/owasp

RUN wget -c https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/releases/download/v2.11.0/ZAP_2_11_0_unix.sh -P /home/owasp

RUN chmod u+x /home/owasp/ZAP_2_11_0_unix.sh

ENTRYPOINT ./home/owasp/ZAP_2_11_0_unix.sh

CMD ${DEFAULT_PARAMS}
```

Comment: Actually the input to the script are sequential, like one after the other, like aceeting terms and conditions, so its not just one set of inputs...it is like script runs, asks for the input and resumes installing and then again continues installation and then again asks for user input. With your example what i understood is, running script with one time set of inputs

Comment: Is it a custom script? You can force Ubuntu to be a non input device via: ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive instead of ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive.

Comment: No its not a custom script. Its an installation script to install the an application

Comment: Try to set the ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive at the top of your Dockerfile, right under FROM ubuntu:20.04. This forces ubuntu to disable interactive mode.